# Parsing json with a nested element

Tags: php, json, parsing

does not work with a nested element
the elements of the first level are output, and the nested array with data is not read, as it is possible to get  values - id, title and location?

```
<?php

function removeBomUtf8($s){
  if(substr($s,0,3)==chr(hexdec('EF')).chr(hexdec('BB')).chr(hexdec('BF'))){
        return substr($s,3);
    }else{
        return $s;
    }
}

$url = "https://denden000qwerty.000webhostapp.com/opportunities.json";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$clean_content = removeBomUtf8($content);
$decoded = json_decode($clean_content);

while ($el_name = current($decoded)) {
 // echo 'total = ' . $el_name->total_items . 'current = ' . $el_name->current_page . 'total = ' . $el_name->total_pages . '<br>' ;
    echo ' id = ' . $el_name->data[0]->id . ' title = ' . $el_name->data.title . ' location = ' . $el_name->data.location . '<br>' ;
  next($decoded);
}
?>
```

Comment: what are the things you want to parse?

Comment: "data":[{"id":412235,"title":"We Speak English","lat":"10.6966159","lng":"-74.8741045","url":"https://gis.aiesec.org/v2/opportunities/412235","status":"open","current_status":"open","location":"Sabanalarga, Colombia","city":"AtlÃ¡ntico, Colombia","programmes":{"id":1,"short_name":"GV"},"applications_count":54,"is_favourited":false,"branch":{"id":321136,"name":"@ UNIATLÃNTICO","organisation": etc...

Comment: i need get - "id":412235,"title":"We Speak English" city":"AtlÃ¡ntico, Colombia"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$el_name->data[0]->id` is correct

`$el_name->data.title` is not

you see the difference?

and `$decoded` is the root (no need to iterate over it) - you want to iterate over the `data` children

```
<?php
foreach($decoded->data as $data)
{
    $id = (string)$data->id;
    $title = (string)$data->title;
    $location = (string)$data->location;


    echo sprintf('id = %s, title = %s, location = %s<br />', $id, $title, $location);
}
```